# Configuration-specific exclude from build for Content items

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

Windows Phone 8, C# project. I have some content files that go into my app package as resources (build type "Content"). Depending on build configuration (Debug vs. Release), I want to exclude some of them from the build process. Can I? There's nothing in the properties window to that effect. However, in C++ projects I can do that to individual source files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also go into the .csproj file and edit it manually. There you can set various properties for this. Ie, add this to whatever you want to only apply to a specific build:
        Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' "

Example:
    <Content Include="Assets\ReleaseImage.png" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' " />
    <Content Include="Assets\DebugImage.png" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' " />

Comment: Good one! Can you make a Condition that matches several configs?

Comment: yeah. check out the doc on msdn regarding csproj schema. You can also learn a lot from just looking at the csproj files you got.

Answer (score 1):

Not the easiest but you could run a post build event on the command-line and use macros to help you.

The macro - $(ConfigurationName) will help with your debug.

[Post Build Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)

[Helpful Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx)

Comment: Solved with a pre-build event that does some renaming based on config. So ugly.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Yea it is ugly but once you write the script to copy only a few files the rest is easy. It would be nice to do it based on the configuration but that is not allowed at the file level.

Comment: Sorry, dotMorten's way is much better.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev ohh I agree. Did not know that was possible